# UserProfileProperties why is it Dictionary<string, string> rather than a Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

When I connect to sharepoint using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (Sharepoint 2013 Client components SDK) to retrieve my profile properties. I am amazed to see that the .UserProfileProperties member of the PersonProperties class is a Dictionary<string, string> rather than a Dictionary<string, object>!

The problem I have is that there are field values in there that I would like to get too that are byte arrays, but because the value is a string, all i can see is a piece of text that looks like "System.Byte[]". ha!

Is there another way I can get the actual proper value out of the .UserProfileProperties collection - rather than having it's string representation?

Thanks!

```
var context = new ClientContext(url); 
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
var myProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();
context.Load(myProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.Email, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

then inspect myProperties.UserProfileProperties

Comment: `there are field values in there that I would like to get too that are byte arrays` - how did you get byte arrays in there in the first place if it's a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Just by inspecting the dictionary with the debugger. Perhaps you don't understand. The values in the collection of userprofileproperties are all strings! so if the profile property is called 'XXX' you can tell by its value what type it is. Because all it is doing deep down when the value is put into the dictionary is just calling object.ToString() on it. A byte array ToString() will just give you "System.Byte[]" as its value. I can guess by that text what type it is.

Comment: You're right, I didn't note the significance of you using the Client components wrapper. My bad :)

Comment: Hey there. Its not actually me putting values into the dictionary. I am just trying to read them. Somewhere deep in the dark reaches of the sharepoint client sdk it does. Silly thing is they chose the wrong dictionary type to store the values! Crazy.